# Como especificar o enctype de um gravity form?

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou usando Wordpress com Gravity Forms. Tenho um formulário que estou usando para submeter dados para um site tercerizado. O detalhe, esse site está esperando que os dados sejam enviados da forma `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, mas o Gravity Forms está mandando como `multipart/form-data`. No final, não consigo receber a resposta certa do site tercerizado.

Olhando para o `<form />` que o Gravity Forms gera, vejo que tem o tag `enctype="multipart/form-data`. Será que tem um meio de colocar por meio do gravity forms o `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema. É simplesmente usar o hook `gform_form_tag_{form_id}` dentro do meu plugin.

Este hook pode ser usado para colocar qualquer coisa que queira dentro do `<form />` (sendo parâmetros). Do jeito que eu acabei usando é utilizando um `pregreplace( )` para mudar só o que queria e deixar o resto em pax.

Documentação sobre o hook se encontra aqui: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_form_tag